# iptables Port Forwarding

Tags: linux, iptables, port-forwarding

I have a web server running on my server on port 7000. I want it to be accessible on port 80. I've read that this could be easily done with iptables port forwarding. What would the correct command would be to achieve that?

E

Comment: It my be easier/better just to change your webserver config.  Do you use apache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iptables command:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 7000
```

Change eth0 to your external interface name.

Comment: what about POSTROUTING and FORWARD chains ? its not true what You have wrote...